# Integrating functions in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The following is a True/False problem from an exam I got back:

If $f'(x)=1$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(2)=7$ then $f(-2)=-7$.

I said false for this problem, but it was marked wrong. My reasoning for this was to treat this as an initial value problem. First, integrate $f'(x)$ so that $f(x)=\int f'(x)dx=x+c$. Next solve for $c$ from $f(2)=7$. Thus $2+c=7\implies c=5$. So our function is $f(x)=x+5$ where $f'(x)=1\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f(2)=7$. Both of the statements in the AND statement in the hypothesis are true, therefore the hypothesis is true. Next, checking $f(-2)=3\neq-7$ therefore the conclusion of the implication is false. Here we have True imply false, therefore the implication is false.

Is there an error in my rationale?

Comment: Everything you show is correct.  My best thought is if you have not discussed integration within the context of the real analysis class, you must use only the theorems / definitions covered thus far in class, and need to use an argument based on the mean value theorem or similar.

Comment: The exam was graded on a raw score of whether or not we chose the correct answer, so no explanations were necessary. In the post, I wanted to be confident in my response so I wrote out my thoughts. Also, I didn't want to appear that I wasn't merely fishing for answers. Though you do have a point with the explanation here. This problem was testing on the MVT, not my skills to solve IVP.

Comment: One potential problem is that what if the ODE has a non-unique solution (well it does as it's a first order linear ODE with CC by a famous theorem). But other than that, it looks correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument is correct. Besides, note that$$\frac{f(2)-f(-2)}{2-(-2)}=\frac{14}4=\frac72.$$But, by the mean value theorem, that quotient should be $1$.

Comment: A classmate noted that she used the MVT for this problem. I didn't remember how exactly she used it, but reading this I can see that your argument matched hers. Much simpler explanation. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.